# Select Excel row --> Create Hashtable from Entries

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, hashtable, xlsx

I have an Excel .xlsx-file which looks like this:

[image]

---

Now I'd like to create a PowerShell script, which can do the following:

1. Ask the User which row he wants to use (for example *4*)
2. Create a hashtable with those entries

The hashtable should look like this:

```
Name                 Value
----                 -----
Name                 Jane Doe
Age                  67
Street               Grace St. 19
Zipcode              12345
Date                 03.03.2013
```

Does someone know how I can achieve this?

Plus: Is this actually achievable with a xlsx-File or do I need to use a CSV-file?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a CSV.  Then you can use `Import-Csv` and `Out-GridView` making it very easy for user-interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more intuitive way is to

- read the excel file directly with the [Import-Excel module](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)
- pipe it to `Out-Gridview`, select a single line
- and populate the hashtable

---

```
$HashTable = [ordered]@{}

Import-Excel "x:\path\sample.xls" | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title "Select one line" | 
  ForEach-Object {$_.psobject.properties | ForEach-Object {
    $HashTable[$_.Name]=$_.Value
  }
}
$HashTable
```

[image]

Sample output:

```
> $HashTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Name                           Molly Johnson
Agr                            35
Street                         Murraay St. 86
Zipcode                        54321
Date                           02.02.2009
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it is achievable if we convert the xls to csv:

```
$excelFilePath = "C:\Temp\abc.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFilePath)

$($Workbook.Worksheets | where {$_.Name -eq "Sheet1"}).SaveAs("C:\Temp\abcd.csv", 6)

$Excel.Quit()
```

I would suggest using an ID instead of row number:

```
$importedAbcd = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\abcd.csv" -Delimiter ";"

[int]$answer = Read-Host "Select ID to work with"
$object = $importedAbcd | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq $answer}
```

You have the row now converting it to hash:

```
$hash = @{}
$object.psobject.properties | Foreach { $hash[$_.Name] = $_.Value }
```